# Remove and add node in php DOMXPath

Tags: xml, domxpath

I am trying to remove certain node from given XML content. At the same time i also want to add additional node to the existing xml for example:

```
$xml_string = '<air:AirPricingInfo xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v48_0" Key="82won53R2BKAcqfvFAAAAA==" TotalPrice="BDT27725" BasePrice="USD234.00" ApproximateTotalPrice="BDT27725" ApproximateBasePrice="BDT19598" EquivalentBasePrice="BDT19598" Taxes="BDT8127" ApproximateTaxes="BDT8127" LatestTicketingTime="2019-11-30T23:59:00.000+01:00" PricingMethod="Guaranteed" ETicketability="Yes" PlatingCarrier="MH" ProviderCode="1G" Cat35Indicator="false"><air:FareInfo FareBasis="NBC6MBD" PassengerTypeCode="ADT" Origin="KUL" Destination="DAC" EffectiveDate="2019-11-21T22:41:00.000+06:00" DepartureDate="2020-02-19" Amount="BDT10301" NegotiatedFare="false" Key="82won53R2BKAbqfvFAAAAA=="/>          <air:FareInfo FareBasis="NBC6MBD" PassengerTypeCode="ADT" Origin="KUL" Destination="DAC" EffectiveDate="2019-11-21T22:41:00.000+06:00" DepartureDate="2020-02-19" Amount="BDT10301" NegotiatedFare="false" Key="82won53R2BKAlqfvFAAAAA=="/><air:BookingInfo BookingCode="N" BookingCount="9" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="82won53R2BKAbqfvFAAAAA==" SegmentRef="82won53R2BKAMqfvFAAAAA=="/><air:BookingInfo BookingCode="X" BookingCount="5" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="82won53R2BKAbqfvFAAAAA==" SegmentRef="82won53R2BKAMqfvFBBB=="/><air:TaxInfo Category="BD" Amount="BDT500" Key="82won53R2BKAdqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:TaxInfo Category="OW" Amount="BDT2000" Key="82won53R2BKAeqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:TaxInfo Category="UT" Amount="BDT3000" Key="82won53R2BKAfqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:TaxInfo Category="G1" Amount="BDT401" Key="82won53R2BKAgqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:TaxInfo Category="H8" Amount="BDT20" Key="82won53R2BKAhqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:TaxInfo Category="MY" Amount="BDT1461" Key="82won53R2BKAiqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:TaxInfo Category="E5" Amount="BDT75" Key="82won53R2BKAjqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:TaxInfo Category="YQ" Amount="BDT670" Key="82won53R2BKAkqfvFAAAAAAA"/><air:FareCalc>DAC MH KUL 111.00NBC6MSBD MH DAC 122.50NBC6MBD NUC233.50END ROE1.0</air:FareCalc>  <air:PassengerType Code="CNN"/><air:ChangePenalty PenaltyApplies="Anytime"><air:Amount>BDT3350.0</air:Amount></air:ChangePenalty> <air:CancelPenalty NoShow="true" PenaltyApplies="Anytime"><air:Percentage>100.00</air:Percentage></air:CancelPenalty></air:AirPricingInfo>';
```

from here I want to remove the node `<air:BookingInfo....>` which has `SegmentRef="82won53R2BKAMqfvFBBB=="` and i also want to change the node `<air:PassengerType Code="CNN"/>` to `<air:PassengerType BookingTravelerRef="child_1" Code="CNN"/>` and add another node along with this `<air:PassengerType BookingTravelerRef="adult_1" Code="ADT"/>`
so far I tried with:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(html_entity_decode($xml_string, ENT_NOQUOTES));
$airNS = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v48_0";
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$test = $xp->query('//air:BookingInfo[not(@SegmentRef="82won53R2BKAMqfvFBBB==")]');
$test = html_entity_decode($test,ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

but it throws an error: " html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given".
I actually want to return the $test as xml content.

Answer (score 0):

Your `html_entity_decode()` calls are harmful. The function converts html and xml entities to characters, but this is done by loading them into DOM internally. So at best the calls do nothing, at worst they destroy the XML.

The return value of `DOMXpath::query()` is a node list and you're treating it as a string. Only `DOMXpath::evaluate()` can return scalar values or node lists depending on the Xpath expression. However you want to modify the nodes, so you will need them. Use `foreach` to iterate the node list.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml_string);
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$airNS = "http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v48_0";
// register the namspace for xpath expressions
$xpath->registerNamespace('air', $airNS);

// fetch matching nodes and delete them
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//air:BookingInfo[@SegmentRef="82won53R2BKAMqfvFBBB=="]') as $bookingInfo) {
    $bookingInfo->parentNode->removeChild($bookingInfo);
}
// look for the passenger info
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//air:PassengerType[@Code="CNN"]') as $passengerType) {
    // change the attribute
    $passengerType->setAttribute('BookingTravelerRef', 'child_1');
    // insert the new node after the current one
    $passengerType->parentNode->insertBefore(
        // create a new element node in the namespace
        $newPassengerType = $document->createElementNS($airNS, 'air:PassengerType'),
        $passengerType->nextSibling
    );
    // set attributes on the new node
    $newPassengerType->setAttribute('Code', 'ADT');
    $newPassengerType->setAttribute('BookingTravelerRef', 'child_1');
}

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```